# Testing for divergence and convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, divergent-series, absolute-convergence

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (1/2)$$

Why/how does this series diverge?

Why doesn't it converge?

Comment: The summand is constant, making it quite easy to calculate the value for any $n$, from that it should be trivial to conclude whether it converges.

Comment: Thats a finite sum not an infinite series. However, an infinite series of constant positive terms will diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n (1/2) = (1/2)\sum_{k=1}^n 1 = (1/2)  n
$$
Given any real number $y > 0$ we see that 
$$
S(n) = (1/2) n > y \iff n > 2y
$$
So we choose $n_0 = 2 \lceil y \rceil$ and then for all $n \ge n_0$ we have $S(n) > y$. This means
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} S(n) = \infty
$$

Comment: but how have you just introduced ^n to the 1/2?

Comment: you've changed the original sum I gave by writing (1/2)n. However my sum is just 1/2, there is no n.

Comment: Your sum says summing up $n$ constant summands, each having the value $1/2$.

Comment: oh i see, thank you :)